# Type name of ampersand and number: &5i

Tags: rust

Running this code

```
extern crate debug;

fn main() {
    let x = &5i;
    println!("{:?}", x);
}
```

prints `&5`. How is this data type called? I would have expected to see something like `a pointer to int`.

`rustc 0.12.0-pre-nightly (09abbbdaf 2014-09-11 00:05:41 +0000)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of `&5i` is `&int`, which is called a reference to `int`, or maybe a shared reference, or an immutable reference.

Incidentally, `"{:?}"` yields a representation of the value based on reflection, not a representation of the type. The only way I'm aware of to get the name of a type is to involve it in a type error.

```
fn main() {
    let i = &5i;
    let () = i;
}
```

but even then you only get it to mention `&int` and `&-ptr` and not a politically correct, up-to-date in common community parlance, prose description.

Comment: Is there any easy way to get the representation of the type?